# Django Formsets: How to properly iterate over forms in a formset and save the corresponding dictionaries

Tags: python, django, forms, dictionary

I have created a formset and I know that form data is being returned as a dictionary. I thought that I could just loop over the forms in a formset and store every dictionary in another dictionary. That doesn't seem to work though, because I am only able to store the latest form (in my template I can dynamically add and remove forms). What I tried was this:

```
def index(request):
data = {}
data['education_data'] = {}
EducationFormSet = formset_factory(EducationForm)
if request.method == "POST":
    persoform = PersonalForm(request.POST)
    education_formset = EducationFormSet(request.POST)
    if persoform.is_valid() and education_formset.is_valid():

        data['personal_data'] = persoform.cleaned_data
        entry = 1
        en = 'entry_%d' % entry
        for form in education_formset:
            data['education_data'][en] = form.cleaned_data
            entry = entry + 1
        print(data)
```

My wanted output would be:

data = {'personal_data':{inputs}, 'education_data': { 'entry_1':{inputs}, ... 'entry_n':{inputs}}}

EDIT:

The problem was the way I tried to add keys to the "Education_Data" key. The following works:

```
for form in education_formset:
    data['education_data']['entry_%d' % entry] = form.cleaned_data
[...]
```